# How can I make custom progress bar in unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints, hud

I am trying to make a health bar. I want a masked progress bar so I tried making another progress bar and moving according to the percent of the health in blueprint. But I couldn't find any documentation about it. How can I do it? Or is it possible? It should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own progress bar by a using shader.

The first thing you should do is mask the uvcoordinates horizontally.`Step function` lets you do this.

> The step() interpolation receives two parameters. The first one is the
>   limit or threshold, while the second one is the value we want to check
>   or pass. Any value under the limit will return 0.0 while everything
>   above the limit will return 1.0.
>
> https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=step

Unreal doesn't have the `step` function, so you can use [if expression](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/ExpressionReference/Math/index.html#if).

[image: If expression]

---

## Making Step Function

You can also use the hlsl `step` function, in the material editor. Make a custom node, with two inputs named A and B.then use below code:

```
if(A < B)
{
return 0;
}
else
{
return 1;
}
```

[image: custom expression]

[image: Step Function]

---

Create widget BluePrint and set this material to your image:

[image: Health Bar]

useful link:
[Gradient Functions](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/Functions/Reference/Gradient/)